# css/Boostrap 4 - Center by viewport

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am pretty new to **html/css/bootstrap 4** and am creating a navbar as of now. Basically I want a **youtube** logo that redirects to a yt channel on the left, spotify logo to spotify creator on the right and in the middle the name of the creator, which is a dropdown for navigating the site. Somehow I managed to do this with one exception - name of the creator isnt centered by viewport, so when I go to create a headline with  they arent aligned horizonally - the name is a bit off center (to the right). How do I go about centering it? - [image: The items both have different centers - image.]

My messy code:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-black">
  <a class="nav-link" style="color:white" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_OvfkWfYRvdkazcOoeJd8Q"><img src="img/yt-logo-dark.png" alt="YouTube" height="25px"></a>
  <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color:white"><h2>KJK Music</h2></a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="about-me">O mně</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="about-site">O stránce</a>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <a class="navbar-link" style="color: white" href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/7vlBedEBJhQlJCl1tpknhi"><img src="img/SpotifyIcon.png" alt="Spotify" height="50px" style="margin:12.5px"></a>
</nav>
```

(Had to do it as a snippet, otherwise the formatting would be even wierder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make horizontal center "KJK Music", it is already centered because your  tag have justify-content-center class. + You can user "text-center" class to make it horizontally centered or text-align:center CSS property.

Comment: The thing is, they are different centers - https://i.imgur.com/hgFphbl.png

Comment: They are different centered because of margin ad paddings of nav block. You can give .dropdown-menu a{
  padding-left: 20px;
} and make it same centered